# Get one element of path string using bash

Tags: command-line, bash, text-processing

I have an ASCII file containing filepaths which I read by running:

```
while read p; do echo $p; done < filelist.txt
```

The file contains filepaths with the following pattern:

```
./first/example1/path
./second/example1/path
./third/example2/path
```

How can I get a specific part of the path string (from `/` to `/` ), e.g.
I need to get an output that prints:

```
first
second
third
```

and also

```
example1
example1
example2
```

I'm sure there is a way of doing this using regular expressions and `sed`, but I'm not familiar with it.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Use `cut`:

```
$ cat filelist.txt
./first/example1/path
./second/example1/path
./third/example2/path

$ cut -d/ -f2 filelist.txt 
first
second
third

$ cut -d/ -f3 filelist.txt 
example1
example1
example2
```

The `-d/` sets the column delimiter to `/` and the `-f2` selects the 2nd column.

You can of course also use Bash variables instead of a file name or pipe data into the `cut` command:

```
cut -d/ -f3 $MyVariable
echo ./another/example/path | cut -d/ -f3
```

Comment: Using `| cut -d/ -f3`  in a pipe did the trick. Thanks! This is the full command now:  
`while read p; do echo $p; done < filelist.txt | cut -d/ -f3`

Comment: @mcExchange There's no reason to use that while loop.  It's far simpler to just do

`cut -d/ -f3 filelist.txt`

Comment: Also, avoiding the while avoids quoting problems, and will not fail with newlines in file names.

Answer (score 10):

You could do it directly in your `read` command, using the `IFS` variable e.g.

```
$ while IFS=/ read -r p1 p2 p3 r; do echo "$p2"; done < filelist.txt 
first
second
third
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use `awk`

```
pilot6@Pilot6:~$ cat filelist.txt
./first/example1/path
./second/example1/path
./third/example2/path

pilot6@Pilot6:~$ awk -F "/" '{print $2}' filelist.txt
first
second
third

pilot6@Pilot6:~$ awk -F "/" '{print $3}' filelist.txt
example1
example1
example2
```

Answer (score 4):

If we want any element of the path, it is best to use something that can break up a string into fields, such as [awk](/questions/tagged/awk), [cut](/questions/tagged/cut) ,[python](/questions/tagged/python), or [perl](/questions/tagged/perl).  However, [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) can also do the job with parameter substitution,using pattern replacement and throwing everything into an array.

```
$> echo ${FILE//\//\ }                                                         
sys class backlight intel_backlight brightness
$> ARRAY=( ${FILE//\//" " } )                                                  
$> echo ${ARRAY[2]}
backlight

$> FILE="./dir1/dir2/file.txt"                                                 
$> ARRAY=( ${FILE//\/" "} )
$> echo ${ARRAY[@]}                                                            
. dir1 dir2 file.txt
$> echo ${ARRAY[1]}
dir1
```

Now we have an array of items made out of the path. Note that if the path contains spaces, it may involve altering internal field separator `IFS` .

Answer (score 1):

Bash and `cut` are the way to go, however an alternative using Perl:

```
perl -F/ -lane 'print(@F[1])' filelist.txt
```

for the second `/`-delimited field and

```
perl -F/ -lane 'print(@F[2])' filelist.txt
```

for the third `/`-delimited field.

- `-l`: enables automatic line-ending processing. It has two separate effects. First, it automatically chomps $/ (the input record separator) when used with -n or -p. Second, it assigns $\ (the output record separator) to have the value of octnum so that any print statements will have that separator added back on. If octnum is omitted, sets $\ to the current value of $/.
- `-a`: turns on autosplit mode when used with a -n or -p. An implicit split command to the @F array is done as the first thing inside the implicit while loop produced by the -n or -p.
- `-n`: causes Perl to assume the following loop around your program, which makes it iterate over filename arguments somewhat like sed -n or awk:

  ```perl
  LINE:
    while (<>) {
        ...             # your program goes here
    }
  ```
- `-e`: may be used to enter one line of program;
- `print(@F[N])`: prints the Nth field.

```
% cat filelist.txt 
./first/example1/path
./second/example1/path
./third/example2/path
% perl -F/ -lane 'print(@F[1])' filelist.txt
first
second
third
% perl -F/ -lane 'print(@F[2])' filelist.txt
example1
example1
example2
```